# Entry point of WebAPI every time it is accessed

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to identify the one point which is hit every time before a request goes to the controller in the webAPI. I need to put in a custom authentication at that point. I am already doing a customAuthorization but I want to tweak in some custom authentication even before it reaches the controller.

The application_Start method only gets triggered once and so I am not quite sure what is the one place where the control goes every time we put in a URL in the browser and hit enter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Gloabal.asax` has more methods, which can be overloaded and one of them is [`Application_BeginRequest`](http://aspalliance.com/1114_Understanding_the_Globalasax_file.3)

And [here's](http://blog.thedigitalgroup.com/chetanv/2015/06/30/a-detailed-walkthrough-of-asp-net-mvc-request-life-cycle/) more detailed lifecycle. Controller factory also might help you intercepting and tweeking requests.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) //Not triggered with PUT
{
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can opt for `ActionFilterAttribute` of Web API. This is triggered for every request that comes in.

Execution pipeline:

> Controller Constructor > ActionFilter's `OnActionExecuting` > Controller action > ActionFilter's `OnActionExecuted`

Simple `ActionFilterAttribute` implementation:

```
public class YourFilterName : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // pre-processing
        //Your authentication logic goes here - use actionContext
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var objectContent = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content as ObjectContent;
        if (objectContent != null)
        {
            var type = objectContent.ObjectType; //type of the returned object
            var value = objectContent.Value; //holding the returned value
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("OnActionExecuted Response " + actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: but isn't this after the request reaches a controller ? I need something even before that. the Application_BeginRequest() works well as of now.But not sure if there is any thing specific to the WebAPI

Comment: Sure you can use `Application_BeginRequest()`. Consider this as the other option.

Comment: and btw, this is filter's code. This is executed just before the request reaches the controller.